# Elasticsearch and Kibana - Kibana server is not ready yet

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I looked everywhere for this error but couldnt find any solution to solve it.

I have to ec2 instances running, one with elasticsearch and one with kibana.

in my browser if i access elasticsearch on port 9200 i am able to retrieve the data.
but if i do the same thing with kibana, i get

```
"Kibana server is not ready yet"
```

i am not an expert with elastic search and kibana, so if anybody could help me to figure out what am i doing wrong.

I post my templates:

this is my kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://10.0.105.100:9200"]


# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"
```

and this is my elasticsearch:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: production
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true

cluster.name: production
node.name: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.0.105.100"]
```

both elasticsearch and kibana are the same version 7.6.2

any idea please?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213012/discussion-on-question-by-hamza-el-aouane-elasticsearch-and-kibana-kibana-serv).

Comment: not from the same issue, however I also got the same error and the culprit log seems to be `[2022-08-01T21:38:15.006+00:00][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] This version of Kibana (v8.3.3) is incompatible with the following Elasticsearch nodes in your cluster: v7.17.3 @ 10.233.77.24:9200 (10.233.77.24), v7.17.3 @ 10.233.81.216:9200 (10.233.81.216), v7.17.3 @ 10.233.66.217:9200 (10.233.66.217)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion on the comments section, I am summarizing the steps which might be useful to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Pinging wasn't happening from Kibana to Elaticsearch, which could be that port on elasticsearch is not open for kibana, which can be resolved by allowing the port access on elasticsearch, as these are(ES and kibana) are running on ec2 instances, it can be configured in AWS security setting.
2. Elasticsearch is running on loopback address ie localhost or 127.0.0.1 which can be changed by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61548156/4039431) SO answer.
3. [Github issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/25806) can help you understand issue in detail if the above steps don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
May  3 11:37:38 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:38Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":794,"message":"No living connections"}
May  3 11:37:41 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:41Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":794,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://10.0.105.100:9200/"}
May  3 11:37:41 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:41Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":794,"message":"No living connections"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd-resolved[645]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd-resolved[645]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping all plugins."}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","bfetch"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","graph"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","apm"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","cloud"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","spaces"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","home"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","share"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","data"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","translations"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","apm_oss"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","security"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","features"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","timelion"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","canvas"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","metrics"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","usageCollection"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","code"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","encryptedSavedObjects"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","infra"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","licensing"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","siem"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","plugins","taskManager"],"pid":794,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":794,"message":"Starting saved objects migrations"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["warning","savedobjects-service"],"pid":794,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Cluster client cannot be used after it has been closed."}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-05-03T11:37:43Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":794,"message":"Error: Cluster client cannot be used after it has been closed.\n    at ClusterClient.assertIsNotClosed (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/elasticsearch/cluster_client.js:187:13)\n    at ClusterClient._defineProperty [as callAsInternalUser] (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/elasticsearch/cluster_client.js:108:12)\n    at callAsInternalUser (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_service.js:72:29)"}
May  3 11:37:43 ip-10-0-105-101 kibana[794]:  FATAL  Error: Cluster client cannot be used after it has been closed.
May  3 11:37:45 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May  3 11:37:45 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  3 11:37:45 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
May  3 11:37:45 ip-10-0-105-101 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
```

The first block of error is due to the ICMP not set yet. but as soon as i allow ICMP, they dont happen again.

Those are all the log i could found about kibana, as i dont have a specific file onlig for kibana.log

Comment: Any luck with my answer ?

Comment: hello joe, sorry but i couldnt rate your answer. yes now it works following you advice. Thank you very much. now i am stuck with mongoose seeding

Answer (score 0):

In the kibana.yml make sure you are pointing to the right instance of Elastic search.
By default it points 9200 port. Incase you have changed the port ,you will need to mention the same in the *elasticsearch.hosts* property in kibana.yml

elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9401"]

Also ,there might be 2 indices on ES *.kibana_task_manager_1* and *.kibana_1* . If their status is NOT green ,it might create a problem.
Deleted these 2 indices and restarted kibana.